# How to pass data between components in React Native

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, mobile

I am wondering how I can get data from components when button is clicked in React Native and pass it to other component. Here is my code:

*This is my input component:*

**ZipInput.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { TextInput } from 'react-native';
import styles from './../assets/style';


export default class ZipInput extends React.Component {

  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = '';
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <TextInput
       style={styles.input}
       onChangeText={(text) => this.setState({text})}
       keyboardType={'numeric'}
       placeholder = {'Enter Zip Code'}
     />
    );
  }
}
```

*This is my button:*

**GoButton.js**

```
import React from 'react';
import { Button, View } from 'react-native';
import styles from './../assets/style';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';


export default class GoButton extends React.Component {
  _handlePress(event) {
    alert('Pressed!');
  }

  render() {
    const {navigate} = this.props.navigateProp
    return (
      <View style={styles.buttonContainer}>
        <Button
          onPress={() =>
            navigate('ZipResultScreen')
          }
          title="GO"
          accessibilityLabel="Find Insurance Quotes"
          color='#fff'
        />
      </View>

    );
  }
}
```

I created the components serparetely and import them in Homescreen.js. From there I will pass the data to other component.

*Here is my Homescreen.js:*

```
import React from 'react';
import { StyleSheet, Text, View, ImageBackground } from 'react-native';
import styles from '../assets/style'
import Header from '../components/header';
import ZipInput from '../components/zipinput';
import InsuranceType from '../components/insurancetype';
import GoButton from '../components/gobutton';
import {StackNavigator} from 'react-navigation';


export default class HomeScreen extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const navigate = this.props.navigation;
    return (
      <View style={styles.container}>
          <Header />
          <ImageBackground
          style={styles.imgbg}
          source={{ uri: 'https://www.expertinsurancereviews.com/wp-content/uploads/2017/03/background-hp-1.jpg' }}
        >
              <View style={styles.intro}>
                <Text style={styles.title}>Compare Insurance Rates</Text>
                <ZipInput  />
                <InsuranceType  style={styles.select} />
                <GoButton navigateProp = {navigate} />
              </View>

          </ImageBackground>
      </View>
    );
  }
}
```

Comment: possible duplicate of https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949187/sharing-data-between-components-in-react

Answer (score 1):

You need to pass your data while navigating to another screen.

Consider following example.

`<Button onPress={() => navigation.navigate('ScreenName', { data: { title: 'Hello World'} })}>`

```
export default class Screen extends React.Component {
  render () {
    const { title } = this.props.navigation.state.params.data

    return (
      <View>
        <Text>{title}</Text>
      </View>
    )
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer but I do not see the solution for getting values from those components I mentioned above. I need to get those values when a button clicked.

Comment: what do you mean by those components and those values? You need to explain better.

Comment: Do you want to pass data from parent component to child? if it's that you want than pass value as props `<GoButton data={data} />`.

Comment: I have 3 Components: Childs: <GoButton>, <ZipInput>,  Parent:
 <HomeScreen>. What I want  is: When <GoButton> clicked, getting value from <ZipInput> and passing it to <HomeScreen> (parent component)

Comment: Add onChangeText props to your ZipInput component as `<ZipInput onChangeText={(zip) => this.setState({zip})}>` then inside ZipInput as `<TextInput onChangeText={this.props.onChangeText}`. I hope it will help you, good luck.

Answer (score 1):

Here is what I found from React Navigation Documentation. It is so easy.

https://reactnavigation.org/docs/params.html

Comment: When you say "data" what exactly do you mean?  If you're talking about passing a string of text as opposed to a full api call there is a big difference.  Passing navigation parameters is just just that parameters.