# The proper way of exchanging objects between sibling components in React

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to build a simple React app and stuck into trouble. I have the following structure:

**App.js**

```js
class App extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PlanBuilder />
        <PlanMenu />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**PlanMenu.js**

```js
class PlanMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return (
      <div className="PlanMenu">
        <button type="button"
          onClick={addObject(
            new CWall({
                x: 100,
                y: 100,
                length: 200
            }))}>Wall
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

**PlanBuilder.js**

```js
class PlanBuilder extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objects: []
    };
  }

  addObject(object) {
    this.setState({
        objects: [...this.state.objects, object]
    });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <Stage>
        <Layer>
          {
          this.state.objects.map(function(object) {
              return object.render();
            })
          }
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    );
}
```

So the main idea is that I have two sibling components: the drawing area and the menu. When the button on the menu is pressed, I want to create a new object and send it to the drawing area element. So, the question is how to pass `PlanBuilder.addObject` method to the `PlanMenu` class. I came from the C world, and what I think about is to pass kinda function pointer to `PlanMenu`. However, I am not sure this is an appropriate solution. Would you please recommend me the proper way of doing this in React? Thank you in advance.

Comment: functions can be called through props, I assume you want change the state by adding new object to it. What you can do is create state in the parent component and addObject() should also be implemented in parent as well, you can pass this method through props to the child component, the same way you can pass the state to another child. I would recommend using central state management tool such as redux will give more efficient way to handle complicated scenarios. This link might help https://stackoverflow.com/questions/37949187/sharing-data-between-components-in-react

Comment: It's hard to pass a method to the same level component. So you need to use parent and child components or global state.

Comment: you need to create the function in the parent component and save the data in a state. Then pass down the function and it's value to child, and whenever you need it, call the function from the child or use its current value.

Comment: can you share us the `addObject()` function implementation?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In this case you have two ways.

The simpler one is to move the logic you have on PlanBuilder to App, and pass the necessary props to PlanBuilder and PlanMenu, like:

```
class PlanMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { addObject } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="PlanMenu">
        <button type="button"
          onClick={addObject(
            new CWall({
                x: 100,
                y: 100,
                length: 200
            }))}>Wall
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PlanBuilder extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { objects } = this.props

    return (
      <Stage>
        <Layer>
          {objects.map(function(object) {
            return object.render();
          })}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objects: []
    };

    this.addObject = this.addObject.bind(this)
  }

  addObject(object) {
    this.setState({
        objects: [...this.state.objects, object]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { objects } = this.state

    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PlanBuilder objects={objects} />
        <PlanMenu addObject={this.addObject} />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

The other alternative is to create a "Container" to hold the logic instead adding it to App, like:

```
class PlanMenu extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { addObject } = this.props

    return (
      <div className="PlanMenu">
        <button type="button"
          onClick={addObject(
            new CWall({
                x: 100,
                y: 100,
                length: 200
            }))}>Wall
        </button>
      </div>
    );
  }
}

class PlanBuilder extends React.Component {
  render() {
    const { objects } = this.props

    return (
      <Stage>
        <Layer>
          {objects.map(function(object) {
            return object.render();
          })}
        </Layer>
      </Stage>
    )
  }
}

class PlanContainer extends React.Component {
  constructor(props) {
    super(props);
    this.state = {
      objects: []
    };

    this.addObject = this.addObject.bind(this)
  }

  addObject(object) {
    this.setState({
        objects: [...this.state.objects, object]
    });
  }

  render() {
    const { objects } = this.state

    return (
      <div>
        <PlanBuilder objects={objects} />
        <PlanMenu addObject={this.addObject} />
      </div>
    )
  }
}

class App extends React.Component {

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <PlanContainer />
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

In my opinion, creating a Container makes your code more readable, reusable and cleaner :)

Hope it help!

Comment: Thank you very much! Just want to mention for future readers that there was a problem in my code: instead of
```onClick={addObject(...)}``` it should be  ```onClick={() => { addObject(...) }}```. The first instruction is **calling** the function but the second is **passing** it.

Comment: @kasom Today I've written an article on Medium based on your question! 
You can read it here: https://medium.com/@guilherme.toti/the-right-way-to-use-function-as-parameter-b1f325311e93